# Oracle SQL Case statement checks the result of a SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a very huge query, this query has a lot of Case statements within the select statment. Right now I'm struggling with the following case

```
select .... 
   case 
      when (select name from location where document = xyz) != ''
      then <do something>
      else <do something else>
   end
.
.
.
```

How should I check the condition in the above when statement? It seems to not work right now as it is always entering the else block. All I'm trying to check is if the query returns anything or just null.

Comment: Is it possible name is null instead of an empty string? Also is it possible the string is white space and not empty?

Comment: Oracle does not have empty strings.  Check for NOT NULL.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yup, nont null wrked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the @OldProgrammer I've modified it to the following. It worked.

```
select .... 
   case 
      when (select name from location where document = xyz) is not null 
      then <do something>
      else <do something else>
   end
.
.
.
```

Comment: In WHEN condition it is better to use "(select count(*) from location where document = 'xyz' and name is not null) > 0" - (your query will return error if the "select name ..." return more then one row)

Comment: @Multisync That is a valid point. In my case it returns only one row so 'is not null' is appropriate.